# Unable to link media in CKeditor

Tags: media, wysiwyg

My setup is as follows:

Drupal 7.34
Media 7.x-2.0-alpha3
CKEditor 4.4.6.08188c4

My problem is:

When I add an image from the "library" via media browser in CKeditor and try and link it via the "link" icon - the image does not link up. If I switch to source view I can see that no  tags have been added. If I save page - image link is not applied.

However, the link is saved if I edit source and add link  tags in manually.

[image: example]

Comment: Have you checked to see if there are any JS errors in the console?

Comment: @ShawnConn - No console errors

Comment: I've had similar issues/realizations. Can you remember if it WOULD add the <a> tags, but rather than surround the element in it, create two at each ends of the element that both opened and closed. So turning "<a>stuff</a>" into "<a></a>stuff<a></a>"? If so, I'm petty sure it's all about the media module tokens and using view modes.

Answer (score 1):

From the question details it is not clear if you're using the [CKeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module, or it you're using the [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module in combination with the CKEditor library (so without the CKeditor module).

As a possible alternative to consider, I'd suggest you try this:

- if you're using the [CKeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module, then replace the 4.4.6 ... version of CKeditor with some 3.6.x version of it (such as CKEditor version 3.6.6.1.7696), and see if your problem is resolved (the 4.x version is known to have "some" issues which don't exist in the 3.x version ...).
- alternatively, use the WYSIWYG module (without the CKeditor module, but only using the CKEditor library with version 3.6.6, since WYSIWYG module does not support the 4.x version yet ...). In this case, you may also want to experiment with the various '*cleanup and output*' options within `/admin/config/content/wysiwyg/profile/your_txt_fmt/edit` (with '`your_txt_fmt`' the text format you're using, eg '`filtered_html`').